# How to loop through inner HTML

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml, appendchild

I need to loop through an article and get the heading and first paragraph and append it into another section id. I have this loop, it gets the h4 and p but how do i get the innerHTML? Thanks in advance.

```
function a(x) {
let result = document.getElementsByTagName(x);
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log(result.length);
   }
   console.log(result);
}
window.onload = function(){
    a ("h4");
    a ("p");
}
```

Comment: maybe result[i].innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `innerHTML` property using the current *index*:

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: and how do i tag just the first <p>? where do i put that in?